# Chaquopy fails to install qiskit

Tags: python, android, quantum-computing, qiskit, chaquopy

Hello I am trying to build an app with Chaquopy(12.0.0) and qiskit(0.34.2). The gradle sync is happening fine. But when I go and build the app and install it on my phone. it give error for the qiskit package as **ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:**. The other package are installing fine, and the app is running, with other python function being called, just qiskit is giving problem.

I tried to used python 3.8, but gives the same error, my current python version is 3.9

gradle version(8.0)
Here's my gradle file

```
python {
        buildPython "C:/Program Files/python/python3.8/python.exe"

        pip {
            // A requirement specifier, with or without a version number:
            install "numpy"
            install "qiskit==0.36.2"
            install "matplotlib"

        }
    }
```

here is the python file I am using

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_state_qsphere
from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_bloch_multivector

def bv(num):
    return "test return"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the last pure-Python version of qiskit was 0.7.0, so you could give that a try. Newer versions all contain native components, so they'd need to be built specifically for Android. For more details, see [this Chaquopy issue](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/643).